# How do I locate the server on which my configured CRM 2011 email router is installed?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

From the machine on which Dynamics CRM is installed, where is the pointer that tells me where the associated email router is installed?

Comment: Hey there, what have you already tried? What is the requirement you are trying to solve?

Comment: e-mails are not being sent for a particular CRM deployment, so I wanted to take a look at the CRM email router, but I had no idea where to find it because the email router is located on another virtual machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific pointer. The E-Mail router is not registered as a service for the deployment, so it will not be listed in the Deployment Manager.

As it connects to the CRM with Web Services, the CRM itself does not know whether an E-Mail Router does exist or not. There is not a registration on the CRM side. You have to tell the Router, where it finds its CRM deployment(s) and Mail Server (s).

Comment: So if emails are not being sent by a CRM deployment and googling all says to go check the email router and you don't know which machine hosts the email router, do you have any tips for figuring it out?

Comment: @TimPartridge if you really have absolutly no clue, you would have to look into the trace files for example. Maybe you will find some hint there